# graphql query in 8Base results in null even though I have a one row of test data in there

Tags: graphql

I have a table in my 8base workspace that is called `item_registration` and only one row of test data. My query is:

```
query {
  item_registration {
    product_Name
    type
    description
  }
}
```

And the error I get is:

```json
{
   "data": {
      "item_registration":null
   },
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"The request is invalid.",
         "locations":[
            {
               "line":2,
               "column":3
            }
         ],
         "path":[
            "item_registration"
         ],
         "code":"ValidationError",
         "details":{
            "query":"Please specify exactly one filter parameter."
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a single record query without passing an identifying attribute (i.e. record ID). If you want to get a list of records, use the `item_registrationsList` operation. Or update your query to be:

```
query($id: ID!) {
  item_registration(id: $id) {
    product_Name
    type
    description
  }
}
```